# Webcam picture straight to file attachment

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, webcam

So I have a form, and in this form a user can upload a picture. As an alternative, I want them to be able to take a picture and upload that instead.

---

Now I figure that when a user takes a picture with some sort of flash webcam interface, that picture needs to be stored in some sort of intermediary memory while the user completes his/her form.

Is there a way around this? What's the best solution?

I figure there are only really two options.

> Either (a) I hold the temporary photo and then accept it again once the form is submitted or (b) the user takes a picture, it's downloaded onto their local machine, and they have to choose it as a file to be submitted again.

Neither of these solutions are really satisfactory to me, so I wanted to know if there's any better way to do this.

**Edit:**  As an added bonus, although it's not really relevant, I'm making a Rails app with Paperclip for file attachments. Also, I prefer to work with jQuery...

*Also just general opinions from experienced UI web developers would be nice..*

Comment: You can make use of HTML's `canvas` to hold picture data taken from webcam to a `div` and then save it when user submits the form. I did this nearly 8 to 9 month ago. You want the code implementation? or looking for a best practice type of answer?

Comment: Facebook/ Google has implemented it well. Probably, check them out.

Comment: @Surya Yes please, a code implementation would be VERY helpful.

Comment: @Surya And also links to the FB/Google stuff you're talking about if possible.

Comment: I was talking about the Facebook and Google webcam interface,  they've build for users to capture their profile pictures. I referenced that for a UX and UI perspective. You can see their nicely done UI there.. especially Google+'s UI is amazing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd used this: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ in my rails application for capturing an image from a webcam. You can download this jQuery-webcam here: https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam

Here is a roughly done implementation, sorry for the messy code:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  require 'base64'
    def capture
      # do something
      render :layout => "webcam"
    end

    def save_image
      image = params[:capture][:image]
      File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/path_you_want_to_image/image_name.png", 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(Base64.decode64(image))
      end
      # Or use paperclip to save image for a model instead!!
    end
end
```

**views/layouts/webcam.html.erb**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Application Name</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.webcam"%>
  <script>
      !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
  </script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body> 
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**views/pictures/capture.html.erb**:

```
  <div id="webcam">
   <p>Capture image here!</p>
  </div>

  <%= form_for(save_image_pictures_path, :method => "post", :remote => true) do |f|%>
    <%= hidden_field(:item, :sku)%>
    <div id="capture_images"><input id="capture_image" type="hidden" value="" name="capture[image]"></div>
    <%= submit_tag "Capture Image", :onClick=>"javascript:capture_image();"%>  
  <% end %>     
  <%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
   <p>
     <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
   </p>

<script type="text/javascript">

var pos = 0;
var ctx = null;
var cam = null;
var image = null;

var filter_on = false;
var filter_id = 0;

function changeFilter() {
    if (filter_on) {
        filter_id = (filter_id + 1) & 7;
    }
}

function capture_image(){
    webcam.capture();
    changeFilter();
    void(0);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img     = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var item_image = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") ;
    document.getElementById('capture_images').innerHTML="<input id=\"capture_image\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+item_image+"\" name=\"capture[image]\">";
}

function toggleFilter(obj) {
    if (filter_on =!filter_on) {
        obj.parentNode.style.borderColor = "#c00";
    } else {
        obj.parentNode.style.borderColor = "#333";
    }
}

  jQuery("#webcam").webcam({

    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/javascripts/jscam_canvas_only.swf",

    onTick: function(remain) {

        if (0 == remain) {
            jQuery("#status").text("Cheese!");
        } else {
            jQuery("#status").text(remain + " seconds remaining...");
        }
    },

    onSave: function(data) {

        var col = data.split(";");
        var img = image;

        if (false == filter_on) {

            for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
                var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
                img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
                pos+= 4;
            }

        } else {

            var id = filter_id;
            var r,g,b;
            var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

            for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
                var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);

                /* Copied some xcolor methods here to be faster than calling all methods inside of xcolor and to not serve complete library with every req */

                if (id == 0) {
                    r = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                    g = 0xff;
                    b = 0xff;
                } else if (id == 1) {
                    r = 0xff;
                    g = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                    b = 0xff;
                } else if (id == 2) {
                    r = 0xff;
                    g = 0xff;
                    b = tmp & 0xff;
                } else if (id == 3) {
                    r = 0xff ^ ((tmp >> 16) & 0xff);
                    g = 0xff ^ ((tmp >> 8) & 0xff);
                    b = 0xff ^ (tmp & 0xff);
                } else if (id == 4) {

                    r = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                    g = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                    b = tmp & 0xff;
                    var v = Math.min(Math.floor(.35 + 13 * (r + g + b) / 60), 255);
                    r = v;
                    g = v;
                    b = v;
                } else if (id == 5) {
                    r = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                    g = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                    b = tmp & 0xff;
                    if ((r+= 32) < 0) r = 0;
                    if ((g+= 32) < 0) g = 0;
                    if ((b+= 32) < 0) b = 0;
                } else if (id == 6) {
                    r = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                    g = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                    b = tmp & 0xff;
                    if ((r-= 32) < 0) r = 0;
                    if ((g-= 32) < 0) g = 0;
                    if ((b-= 32) < 0) b = 0;
                } else if (id == 7) {
                    r = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                    g = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                    b = tmp & 0xff;
                    r = Math.floor(r / 255 * r1);
                    g = Math.floor(g / 255 * r2);
                    b = Math.floor(b / 255 * r3);
                }

                img.data[pos + 0] = r;
                img.data[pos + 1] = g;
                img.data[pos + 2] = b;
                img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
                pos+= 4;
            }
        }

        if (pos >= 0x4B000) {
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            pos = 0;
        }

    },

    onCapture: function () {
        webcam.save('/product_capture');

        jQuery("#flash").css("display", "block");
        jQuery("#flash").fadeOut(100, function () {
            jQuery("#flash").css("opacity", 1);
        });

    },

    debug: function (type, string) {
        jQuery("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
    },

    onLoad: function () {

        var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
        for(var i in cams) {
            jQuery("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");
        }
    }
});

function getPageSize() {

    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {
        xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
        yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
        xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
    } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
        xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    var windowWidth, windowHeight;

    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        } else {
            windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
        }
        windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
        windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
        windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
    if(yScroll < windowHeight){
        pageHeight = windowHeight;
    } else {
        pageHeight = yScroll;
    }

    // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
    if(xScroll < windowWidth){
        pageWidth = xScroll;
    } else {
        pageWidth = windowWidth;
    }

    return [pageWidth, pageHeight];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    jQuery("body").append("<div id=\"flash\"></div>");

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "/images/rails.png";
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 129, 89);
        }
        image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
    }

    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {

    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);
</script>
```

Just make sure that, "**jscam.swf**" file referenced in jquery.webcam.js is loaded on page properly.

routes you can define in your **routes.rb** are:

```
resources :pictures do
  collection do 
    get 'capture'
    post 'save_image'
  end
end
```

From here, you can then use this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for uploading it using an Ajax form submission!!

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the very complete answer. I'll be looking into it in the upcoming weeks to I'll be sure to let you know, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A couple questions: what are the window eventlisteners doing at the end of capture.html.erb? Also onCapture calls webcam.save('/product_capture');.... But I don't see that in your routes.

Comment: @varatis I've pasted only required code to make this jQuery-webcam work with your application. `webcam.save('/product_capture')` in onCapture event was just a test to  post the image data to `product_capture` path from its callback method. But, that kind of didn't work for me. Just check if, that callback method works for you by creating a post **route** for `product_capture`. Don't worry, the solution I've posted here is working, if it doesn't work for you, let me know, I can provide my actual code. Which is kind of big and messy, I did all this when I was a newbie to rails.. :P

Comment: @varatis I'm kind of hate my own badly written old codes. Sometimes I wonder, is that all what I did here? I wish I'd time to go back and re-write whole code base again :D BTW, this: `window.addEventListener("load", function(){ #js }` is used to add an initial image before ActionScript i.e. Flash in **canvas** can take place. As you can see on this website: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin that white "X" image. And, `window.addEventListener("resize", function(){ #JS }` to re-size the flash window according to the resolution of a client/ user window. Which makes sense actually.

Comment: @varatis How did you integrate it with paperclip? What changes did you do in `save_image`. I want to upload the image to amazon s3 or Google Drive.

Comment: @Peeyush I think once you get this image at path: `"#{Rails.root}/public/path_you_want_to_image/image_name.png"` within `save_image` method. You can just attach the image to paperclip as normal image uploads using your model which has paperclip methods included.

Comment: Thanks very much @Surya I tried running the code in my rails 4 application but `params[:capture][:image]` seems to be empty and hence although image is created in the folder but it cannot be viewed(as it contains nothing)! I changed `<%= form_for(save_image_pictures_path, :method => "post", :remote => true) do |f|%>` to `<%= form_tag(controller: "pictures", action: "save_image", method: "post", remote: true) do %>` and `params[:canvas][:image]` to `params[:capture][:image]`.

Comment: It's best you create an another question with the relevant code. It's hard to troubleshoot an issue and to look for code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Errors.

Replace

```
def save_image
  image = params[:canvas][:image]
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/path_you_want_to_image/image_name.png", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(Base64.decode64(image))
  end
  # Or use paperclip to save image for a model instead!!
end
```

by the

```
def save_image
  image = params[:capture][:image]
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/path_you_want_to_image/image_name.png", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(Base64.decode64(image))
  end
  # Or use paperclip to save image for a model instead!!
end
```

and

```
function capture_image(){
webcam.capture();
changeFilter();
void(0);
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img     = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var item_image = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") ;
document.getElementById('capture_images').innerHTML="<input id=\"capture_image\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+capture_image+"\" name=\"capture[image]\">";}
```

to

```
function capture_image(){
webcam.capture();
changeFilter();
void(0);
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img     = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var item_image = img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "") ;
document.getElementById('capture_images').innerHTML="<input id='capture_image' type='hidden' value=\'"+item_image+"\' name='capture[image]'>";}
```

After this, all work fine.

PS. If you got: "capture_image() is not a f-n", change f-n name to: "capture_images()" don't forget change name on the onClick event

Comment: corrected the code, thank you for being vigilant and reaching out. I appreciate it.